# Custom Report Type with name space

Tags: custom-report-type

I created a custom report type with custom object Job as primary object and joined with task object just because the report type name and label can't be changed with the default report type. However when I deployed to the environment with namespace I can't see the report but get "Obsolete Report" error but. I have no problem when I deploy to the environment without namespace. Has anyone meet this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the problematic target environment have "allow activities" (= Tasks & Events) ticked on the Job object's definition? Are you able to create that report type from scratch in that environment?
2. Is the report type marked as deployed or "in development"?

Comment: 1. Yes I have enabled those checkbox and I can create the report from scratch using those custom report. 2. The status of the report type is "deployed". Funny thing is that I develop the report on the environment with namespace and it works, but once I download the report on my local and redeploy the report to the environment again using ant it stops working "Obsolete Report" error

Comment: Not sure what else it might be... The report type exists in both envs? What if you force access the report in edit mode - slap `/e` at the end of the URL? It might be something with namespaces - for example check if report definition you deploy mentions the `ns__Report_Type__c` instead of just `Report_Type__c`. Same with all custom fields in the report I guess. Tricky!

Comment: The metadata doesn't have the namespace. If I select default report type ( salesforce generates ) it works fine. Just the custom report type I have problem with

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is going to be the answer but finally I resolved "Obsolete Report" error. This only starts show up when I create a report with join formated with namespace. I can create a joined format report in the namespace environment, but once you download it to my local environment and deploy to the same environment it starts giving me the "Obsolete Report". I know the report is not updatable so I create the same report with different but the result is still the same. However, if I create managed packaged from the environment and deploy to different environment all the sudden my report starts working. But just in case someone run into issue and blocked by this you might want to try to create a package and deploy and it might work. I hope the salesforce fix this issue so developers don't get flustrated from this error.